# I'm trying to install rails and I think I just broke my Ubuntu installation, any help?

Tags: apache2, ruby, rails

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide to install ruby on rails to work with Apache and Passenger. I have followed it step for step and done every command in verbatim. Soon after running

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

and inserting

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main
```

I received this error on my toolbar:

[image]

I tried to delete the file but it can't be deleted. Can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: I have attempted both of those commands and the error still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plan A:

Running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Installing any unmet dependencies, and possibly then doing a restart should fix it.

### Plan B:

Otherwise you should edit the file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

Once more and remove the line you added, then save the file and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And the error should be gone (although a restart may also be necessary for the error to go away as I often find this is necessary even after the problem itself is fixed).

### Plan C:

And finally if all of that failed, delete the file. As this file will be owned by `root`, you will need to use `sudo` to raise your privileges in order to delete it:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

The file should now have been removed, so run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And now the error should be gone.

Comment: Man, Plan B was so easy, how did I not think of that? Thank you very much!

Comment: @ZachLandry: You're welcome! Also, as you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means: [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**

Comment: Just to throw this in for anyone else who runs into this guide and gets the same error... I had to change the file permissions to delete the file. Simply removing the line didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ZachLandry: Ok, I have added that as **Plan C**... ;D